# Check supported architectures of iOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I check supported archs of my apps (ex. MyApp.app)?

This folder is product after building by Xcode.

I use command: "file MyApp.app/MyApp" and it shows:

```
Mach-O executable arm
```

What is this?

I really want to know which architectures it supports (armv6, armv7, armv7s or i386).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `lipo -info MyApp.app/MyApp` to see what architecures are supported.

Comment: Thanks,simple and effective.